# Android: How do I use activities provided from other apps?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to use activities that are not bundled with my app. How could I do that? Using intents or something? I am sure it must be simple.

### UPDATE

The main problem is that I can't actually do this:

```
new Intent(this, SomeExternalActivity.class))
```

because I can't import the class (it's an external app). Something similar, using a string or something.

Thanks a lot!

### UPDATE

This one doesn't work either:

```
new Intent(this, Class.forName("com.somepackage.SomeExternalActivity");
```

Comment: add an intent filter in ur mainfest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only start activities bundled with your app with this constructor:

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

You will need to use one of the following to access an external activity:

```
Intent(String action)
Intent(String action, Uri uri)
```

In your case you would use this intent:

```
new Intent("com.somepackage.SomeExternalActivity");
```

Also note that to access an activity in another app, that app needs to give access to it's activity (through AndroidManifest.xml)

Check the following for more explanation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example, for the [RemoteDroid](http://www.remotedroid.net/)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.setClassName("com.joshsera", "com.joshsera.RemoteDroid"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be *almost* working. However, it throws a `SecurityException` now, saying I'm trying to run code from another app. Any idea which permission do I need to set in my app? By the way, I've seen RemoteDroid before. Nice app.

Comment: @Albus I haven't seen anything scpecial on the Manifest.xml of the _calling_ app. Is the target app one of your own? If so, you've got to set [the exported attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported) to true, I think. In that document, you may want to have a look to the `permission` attribute. According to the docs, the calling Activity must have granted some of the permissions needed for the target Activity.

Comment: Thanks @mdelolmo! I've done exactly what you said. According to the doc the `permission` attribute is automatically set to `true` if the activity has a content filter. In my case, the *called* app has a content filter with to intents: `android.intent.action.MAIN`, `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Comment: Nope. Always that SecurityException saying I can't run code outside my app or something. Thanks for the bother!

Answer (score 1):

The activity you are calling should appear not only in the Manifest for its own package, but in the Manifest for the CALLING package, too.

Comment: Wow. That must have been it. I can't test it at the mo, though.  Thanks!